# Python \ PySpark code: Isn't this an infinite loop?

Tags: python, infinite-loop, pyspark

I was looking through the PySpark code for class pyspark.mllib.feature.IDFModel

at

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.feature.IDFModel.transform

I am confused why this does not create an infinite loop?

This is the code in the class:

```
class IDFModel(JavaVectorTransformer):

  def transform(self, x):
    return JavaVectorTransformer.transform(self, x)
```

and this is the code for the JavaVectorTransformer Class

```
class JavaVectorTransformer(JavaModelWrapper, VectorTransformer):

  def transform(self, vector):
    if isinstance(vector, RDD):
        vector = vector.map(_convert_to_vector)
    else:
        vector = _convert_to_vector(vector)
    return self.call("transform", vector)
```

`IDFModel.transform()` calls `JavaVectorTransformer.transform` which in turn returns `self.call("transform",vector)`

Strangely this seems to work without creating an infinite loop.

Any thoughts?

Comment: self.call is not a call to the same method. There is a method called "call" in the parent class JavaModelWrapper that gets called when self.call is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the code for JavaModelWrapper in the link https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/common.html

self.call is not a recursive call to the same method. There is a method called "call" in the parent class JavaModelWrapper that gets called when self.call is invoked.

Comment: Thank you! Come to think of it.. Duh! Coming from C it wasn't apparent to me that Parent classes in Python are in brackets after the Child Class :)